# Combinatorics Sequences of length 5 from set

Tags: combinatorics

Set = $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f\}$

Let $s$ be a sequence of length $5$ whose elements come from the set.

What is the number of sequences from $s$ that contain at least one number and one letter?

Would the answer be?

1.) Choose 1 letter (6 choices)

2.) Choose 1 number    (10 choices)

3.)                (16 choices)

4.)                (16 choices)

5.)                (16 choices)

Total sequences = $6 \times 10 \times 16 \times 16 \times 16 = 245760$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work, because the first one doesn't necessarily need to be a letter and the second one doesn't necessarily need to be a number.

Assuming that every element can be chosen multiple times, this is a correct solution:

- First count the total number of sequences, which is $16^5$.
- Subtract the number of sequences with numbers only, which is $10^5$.
- Subtract the number of sequences with letters only, which is $6^5$.
- Note that a sequence cannot have numbers only and letters only, and that every sequence that does not have numbers  only and also doesn't have letters only, has at least one letter and at least one number.
- The final answer is $16^5-10^5-6^5=940800$.

Comment: Got it, count what you don't want, I was so close to doing it this way, thanks for the help

Comment: @user3768911 when you have to count the number of ways something happens "at least once", you almost always have to count what you don't want and substract that to the total number of ways